# Xbian update apt-get

Tags: apt, update, xbian

I cannot update my Xbian from the config file,

From sudo xbian-config :
Apt-get update :

```
  w: GPG error: http:/http.debian.net stable release: The follwing I
 have this error
```

Check deb upgrades > Update all available >

```
The Following packages were automatically installed and are no
  consolekit libbind9-80 libck-connector0 libdns88 libffi5 libgssglue1
libisc84 libisccc80 libisccfg82 liblwres80 libparted0debian1 libreadline5 librtmp0
libsystemd-login0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgrated
```

Is it safe to run `apt-get autoremove`?

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  consolekit libbind9-80 libck-connector0 libdns88 libffi5 libgssglue1 libisc84 libisccc80 libisccfg82 liblwres80 libparted0debian1 libreadline5 librtmp0
  libsystemd-login0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 14 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4,053 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `apt-get` knows how to check for unneeded packages and usually doesn't mess up while doing its job.

It saw those packages and knew that they aren't needed anymore since no other packages need them. Plus, you'll gain 4,053 kB of disk space when you let `apt-get` remove those.

It's good practice to run `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get autoclean`after installing/removing/upgrading/downgrading packages. It gets rid of the clutter.